# Datepicker is disappearing on safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery ui datepicker (range) and after I click to open my datepicker if I scroll my page down the calendar is disappearing.I noticed this problem only on safari browser with mobile devices

is there any one who encounter with this problem ?

Could you check my code ?

```js
function datePicker(){
    $( function() {
        var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
            from = $( "#checkin,.checkin" )
                .datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    minDate: 0,
                    beforeShow:function(){
                        $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
                    }
                })
                .on( "change", function() {
                    to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                }),
            to = $( "#checkout,.checkout" ).datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                firstDay: 1,
                minDate: 0,
                beforeShow:function(){
                    $(this).datepicker("widget").addClass("main-datepicker");
                }
            })
            .on( "change", function() {
                from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
            });

        function getDate( element ) {
            var date;
            try {
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
            } catch( error ) {
                date = null;
            }

            return date;
        }
    } );
}

datePicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

From : <input type="text" class="checkin">
To: <input type="text" class="checkout">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code lines from

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

to

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: A tip: to format your code, highlight the code line(s), then either click the **`{}`** button or type Ctrl-K.

Comment: this is not solution I have already use this version in my original project